# Symfony2 preferred directory to place a class

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I'm pretty *new* to Symfony2 and am just wondering what would be the preffered way of doing this.

I have lots of **admin** actions that involve receiving form data and processing it. Naturally, when processing is finished, controller action sends `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('.....'));`.

Now since I have made a JavaScript that submits forms via ajax if browser supports it I need to modify my controller actions to return `Response` object containing `json array` but only if request was sent via ajax.

1. Is it possible to recognize if request sent to controller is AJAX request?
2. Where in directory tree is the preffered place to place class named `ResponseHandler` which would do the redirecting or returning json array based on type of request ? I realized Symfony2 is very strict about these things so I want to get it right from the start. Maybe there is even already bundled solution for this in it?

**Update**

I figured out I can use $this->getRequest->isXmlHttpRequest() in controller.

Question 2 still stands.

Answer (score 0):

> Where in directory tree is the preffered place to place class named ResponseHandler which would do the redirecting or returning json array based on type of request?

If you do an AJAX request you store the data in an parameter, a POST or GET parameter. You can access this parameter in the controller with:

```php
// ...
public function finishAction()
{
    // if you use a GET request
    $data = $this->getRequest->query->get('my-get-parameter');
    // and if you use a POST request
    $data = $this->getRequest->request->get('my-get-parameter');

    // ... do something with the data
}
```

However to answer your question:
The symfony core framework uses the Event Dispatcher component to trigger and attach events. The events are triggered everywhere in the Symfony code. You can attach a class to an event and when that event is triggered, you can change it. That way, you can modify the `Response` object.

Events that are thrown in the code can be found in a `*Events` class in that component. In this case, we want the [`REQUEST`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.php#L23-36) event. Read more on the event dispatcher and how to attach events in the documentation: [Event Dispatcher Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) and [Symfony2 Framework specific documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/index.html).

> I realized Symfony2 is very strict about these things

Symfony really isn't strict about your directory structure. It delivers a default Standard Edition with the recommend structure, but you can change it to make it yours. And if a class is written in the PSR-0 standards symfony will load alle classes you need.